# How to compile against kernel headers?

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling

I'm trying to compile a 3rd-party proprietary driver module, and failing at it. I've installed the `linux-headers-5.4.0` package, but I don't know how to write a gcc command line that will successfully use it.

As a minimal example, consider `test.c`, which does literally nothing but include kernel headers.

```
#include <asm/linkage.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
```

Because the kernel includes both of these files, and can itself be compiled, surely there must be some combination of GCC flags that will result in `test.c` compiling. The proprietary driver's `.c` file includes both of these files among many others, but they're sufficient to demonstrate my problem.

```bsh
eyes=(
  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include            # for linux/module.h
  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/arch/x86/include   # for asm/linkage.h
)
gcc -c "${eyes[@]}" test.c
```

results in

```
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/seqlock.h:36,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/time.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from test.c:2:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/spinlock.h:60:10: fatal error: asm/mmiowb.h: No such file or directory
   60 | #include <asm/mmiowb.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`dpkg -L linux-headers-5.4.0-21 | grep mmiowb.h` shows this file in `include/asm-generic` as well as in `arch/{ia64,mips,powerpc,riscv,sh}/include/asm`. Adjusting my `-I` further to include one of these and the error moves to:

```
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/mmzone.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/gfp.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/umh.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/kmod.h:9,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from test.c:2:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/include/linux/page-flags-layout.h:6:10: fatal error: generated/bounds.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <generated/bounds.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and *this* file simply does not exist on my system, but there is a file called `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-21/KBuild` which looks like a makefile that'd create it, although I cannot figure out how to invoke this makefile.

How can I proceed here? Is there a command I need to run after installing `linux-headers-*` to populate `generated` folders? Is there a guide to this kind of thing online somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux kernel has its own build system based on `make`, which generates the correct `gcc` options for a successful compilation of kernel components and modules.
The `Kbuild` file included in external kernel modules is intended for use with that kernel build system. In addition, external kernel modules should also include a `Makefile` which invokes the kernel build system. A minimal `Makefile` for an external module might look like this:

```
obj-m = foo.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

As you can see, the main `Makefile` of the kernel build system actually resides in the folder `/lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build`, where `$(KVERSION)` is the version number of the kernel you're building for. If you're curious you can try to retrace what the mesh of Makefiles there does and which set of options it ends up calling `gcc` with.

Comment: Thank you. The third-party code included a Makefile that had the `obj-m` line (but none of the rest) and manually running `make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-21-generic/build M=$(pwd) modules` from the shell has built a `.ko`. For posterity, kbuild is documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html).